# CMS replaces HTML/CSS?

Tags: wordpress, web, content-management-system

I recently discovered CMS (SquareSpace, Joomla, Wordpress...) I know that it makes easier to create website. But do CMS replace HTML/CSS/Javascript ? I read that Wordpress can generate HTML pages so I'm not sure.
Could somebody explain me how they work ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its most basic, a CMS assumes two roles:

- Someone who adds the content, who may not know any html/js/css (the administrator)
- A developer who can build the site within the CMS' framework.  Usually this means coding in a server-side language, such as PHP.

CMS pages tend to be dynamically generated, and so what the administrator is actually doing is filling in a database.  The site is then dynamically generated according to the content of this database.

Technically it is actually harder to build a CMS website than a static html/css/js site, but easier for someone to update it when it is built.

The main benefit is if a site is frequently changing than it means someone does not have to go back to their developer every time they want a new page.  The main downside is that it takes longer to build and needs security patches applying.

Answer (score 0):

they use rich text editors as input (jquery added to textarea with formatting tools which auto adds html tags)

it doesn't replace anything, just makes easier content management (CMS stands for content management system), easy to create new pages and formating with familiar methods (MS word like formatting buttons like bold, align right, and so on)

this all just leaves out most of the html and css writing, because that is predifenid in rich text editor and wordpress theme, but in some point you will have to make your own or improvements to existing theme which will be real programming (php, SQL) and html, css coding.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php

to explain what cms is.. try reading the link above

database of the CMS is like the engine
CMS is more of a car frame
the two combined outputs the Car

and old fashion html pages are like the whole car combined